# How to subscribe to event emitter once?

Tags: angular, rxjs, eventemitter, angular2-services, rxjs5

```
// Part of service
public someEvent: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

....

// Component
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `...`
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.service.someEvent.subscribe((x) => {
      // Do something
    });
  }
}
```

`SomeComponent` is displayed in `/` route. When I navigate to different route in my application, and come back again, `SomeComponent` will subscribe to the event again, causing callback to fire twice. How to subscribe to the event once or unsubscribe on destroy of the component and subscribe again?

```
// Can't subscribe after.
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.service.someEvent.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with ngOnInit?

Comment: @micronyks Yes I did, no success though. Also according to [this site](http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/) `ngOnInit` is fired every time just like constructor function, but it waits for child components to initialize.

Comment: `OnInit` is for binding, not gonna work for you... try [`CanReuse`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

Comment: `EventEmitter` is **not** supposed to be used in services but only for `@Output()`s of components and directives. Use `Observable` or `Subject` instead.

Comment: In my case, after I navigate another route and come back again, the subscription is not triggering which I couldn't resolved.

I use it on 'NgOnInit' method, and also have unsubscribe method on 'NgOnDestroy' method

Comment: I have a similar problem.. but still using unsubscribe the issue is there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464655/angular-2-app-events-are-raised-multiple-times

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A call to `subscribe` returns an [instance of `Disposable`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/disposables/disposable.md#disposable-instance-methods), which has a method [`dispose`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/disposables/disposable.md#rxdisposableprototypedispose).

Or if you are using RxJS 5, [`dispose` has been renamed to `unsubscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe) (thanks @EricMartinez).

And from the [RxJS docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS#about-the-reactive-extensions):

> ...when we're no longer interested in receiving the data as it comes streaming in, we call dispose on our subscription.

---

Store the result of your call to `subscribe` and later dispose of the subscription within `ngOnDestroy`.

#### RxJS 5:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.subscription = this.service.someEvent.subscribe((x) => {...});
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

#### RxJS <5:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.subscription = this.service.someEvent.subscribe((x) => {...});
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: In RxJS 5 [dispose was renamed to unsubscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe)

Comment: Thanks! Just like @EricMartinez said, `unsubscribe` instead of `dispose`.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the event emitter firing 1, 2, 3 or more times.  When I add unsubscribe to ngOnDestroy, however, I get "ObjectUnsubscribedError" :(

Comment: Never mind:  I fixed it by doing 
this.subscription = this.service.someEvent.subscribe((x) => {...});
in the constructor

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private _subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this._subscription = this.service.someEvent.subscribe((x) => {
      // Do something
    });
  }
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```